# greenhills multi linker Error "Section .romdata overlaps section .data "

Tags: greenhills, threadx

Please help me with following error-
"[elxr] (error) Section .romdata overlaps section .data" on GHS Multi. This is when a custom Linker Directive file is created for an empty project using threadX. I have also included the search directory for the .ld file in the project(linker Options). How do I ensure that the same .ld file is being used by the elxr Linker. Is it an error with the .ld or some other issue. Also please let me know if any other precautions need to be taken.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the error is that the size reserved for the .romdata section is totally used and the .romdata has overlapped .data.

on your linker script (*.ld) try to extend the size of .romdata.